# SwiftUI onDrop not called?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI's drop API is only fired under certain conditions?

Try dragging the "Drag Me" block over the others.

For some reason, a `TextEditor` needs to satisfy 2 conditions before it's "superview" can detect the drop?

1. have a `background`
2. disabled

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject fileprivate var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    @State private var s1 = "Nope"
    @State private var s2 = "Nope"
    @State private var s3 = "Nope"
    @State private var s4 = "I can detect"
    @State private var s5 = "I can detect"
    @State private var s6 = "Drag me"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            TextEditor (text: $s1)  // drop not detected
                .disabled(true)
            
            TextEditor (text: $s2)  // drop not detected
                .opacity(0.5)
                .disabled(true)
            
            TextEditor (text: $s3)  // drop not detected
                .opacity(0.5).background(Color.pink.opacity(0.5))
            
            TextEditor (text: $s4) // drop detected
                .background(Color.pink.opacity(0.5))
                .disabled(true)
            
            TextEditor (text: $s5)  // drop detected
                .opacity(0.5).background(Color.pink.opacity(0.5))
                .disabled(true)
            
            Text("Yes")            // drop detected
                .background(Color.pink.opacity(0.5))
            
            TextEditor (text: $s6)
                .onDrag { () -> NSItemProvider in
                    return NSItemProvider(object: "Hello" as NSString)
                }
        }.onDrop(of: [.plainText], delegate: viewModel)
    }
}

fileprivate class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, DropDelegate {
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        print("Drop entered: \(info)")
    }
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        print("Drop updated: \(info)")

        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        print("Drop exited: \(info)")
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        print("Perform drop: \(info)")
        return true
    }
}
```

Tested on Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: On MacOS, your code example behaves differently than described in the question / comments. (1) "drag me s6" does not initiate a drag. (2) All editors accept keyboard input except s2. (3) If I move .onDrag to the "Yes" text, it will drop "hello" into every text box, including the one that is keyboard-input-disabled. You may want to also edit your code example to add "s" labels into the placeholder text so that it's clearer to copy-and-paste.

Comment: @Ryan That is interesting. I've only been testing on iOS, seems like it behaves completely different on MacOS?